# Video capture intent causing issues on low RAM device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

The problem is pretty complex.  Basically, I have a FragmentActivity (HomeActivity) that holds a fragment (CategoriesFragment) that holds another fragment (VideoFragment which covers the containing fragment completely when added) that I am using to record video which works great on most devices, but as I test on a SGH-T989 running android 4.1.2 the following happens.  The VideoFragment that records video is gone when I am done recording and the underlying CategoriesFragment is visible.  The `onActivityResult()` of the VideoFragment is not called, instead the HomeActivity `onActivityResult()` is called, but with a different request code than what I used to create the intent. I also get this warning in the log:

`W/FragmentActivity﹕ Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x300c8`

Both of these issues are probably caused by the fragment that sent the intent being destroyed for reason, and so it can't receive the intent result?  Any ideas why this would happen?

Here is the code for creating the intent.

```
//Record Video
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, mVideoLength);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
    // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I've searched for a long time on this one and any help, ideas or theories would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was happening. The activity that created the fragment that started the intent was destroyed on low RAM devices.  The activity was then re-creating the fragment in its onCreate when the intent finished.  You want to let Android OS handle the fragment re-creation if it was responsible for the destruction of the fragment so you just need to add this to your onCreate method

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Create fragments
}else{
    Let the OS create them
}
```